# Regex to replace TO_DATE in string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string that has a TO_DATE function in it. I would like to replace this TO_DATE call with SYSDATE.

For example, my string is basically a SQL insert or update, so I have something like

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col_a, col_b, col_c, updt_dt) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C', to_date('2012-06-11 22:10:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

And I want to replace the TO_DATE call with this:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col_a, col_b, col_c, updt_dt) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C', SYSDATE);
```

Remember, this entire insert statement is in one database field. So, how could I use `regexp_replace` to replace the TO_DATE call with SYSDATE?

I am running Oracle 10gR2.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace the values in the `table_a`?
Or you asking how to modify the query?

Comment: I'm guessing the sql query is a value in a VARCHAR2 field and Nik wants to replace the to_date text with sysdate. So it really has nothing to do with the query, it's just a regexp question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. kentcdodds is correct. The sql statement is a value in a VARCHAR2 field in a table. So, how can I use regexp_replace in my query to replace to_date with sysdate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` on linux:

`sed -e "s/to_date([A-Za-z0-9:' ,-]\+)/sysdate/g" <<< "INSERT INTO table_a (col_a, col_b, col_c, updt_dt) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C', to_date('2012-06-11 22:10:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));"`

If you're not using linux, the find/replace regexp is:

`s/to_date([A-Za-z0-9:' ,-]+)/sysdate/g`

It should be compatible with most of the regexp engines used by editors

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the write direction. My final statement was:
`SELECT regexp_replace(sql_stmt, 'to_date\([A-Za-z0-9:'' ,-]+\)', 'SYSDATE') FROM sample_table;`

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains only one to_date function and if the to_date function has always the same length, then you can use instr to get the position of the first occurence of to_date.

Your statement would roughly look like that:

update ...
  set field = substr(field, 1, instr(..)-1) || 'sysdate' || substr(field, instr(..)+99)
where ..

Comment: There can be multiple occurrences of to_date, however, thinking about it, I would probably be ok just replacing the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I used regular expression to pick out the to_date portion and replace with 'sysdate':  'to_date[^)]*)'